# How to use each iterator to show all the result of @instanceVariable.find().attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have 3 models

1.Project
    
2.Department
    
3.Post

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :projectdepartments
  has_many :departments, through: :projectdepartments
  has_many :posts, as: :postable
end

class Department < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, presence:true
  belongs_to :company
  has_many :projectdepartments
  has_many :projects, through: :projectdepartments
  has_many :posts, as: :postable
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :postable, polymorphic: true 
end
```

a `@project` is `@postable` which has many_to_many association with `@department` and each department has its name

My problem is:
When I use 

**`@postable.departments.first.name`** or 
**`@postable.departments.find(2).name`**
in ***post controller*** it will show the proper result I need respectively like 

"sales", 

"accounting"`.

However, while I need to show them all and use iterator like below

```
@postable.departments.each do |department|
   department.name
end
```

the result become `"department-0x007f26c9993378", "department-0x007f26c9992ae0"`

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController  
  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

  def create    
    @post = @postable.posts.build(post_params)
    @post.user = current_user
    @post.tag = put_tag
    if @post.save
      redirect_to @postable, notice: "Created"
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

 private
   def put_tag
#      @postable.departments.first.name   #This line work if uncomment  
#      @postable.departments.find(2).name #This work fine as well if uncomment 
    @postable.departments.each do |department|
        department.name
    end
  end

  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:content, :user_id, :tag)
  end
end
```

I tried nested iterator and it was still not work.

in view:

```
<% @posts.each do |post|%>
  <%= simple_format post.content %>
  <%= post.tag.map {|t| t}%>
<% end %>
```

My question is, how to show all the result of 

**@postable.departments.first.name**

**@postable.departments.find(2).name** and if there is any 

**@postable.departments.find(3).name** ....etc properly

like 

 "sales", "accounting", "HR" instead of "department-0x007f(random number each time)"

Comment: I think we need more info. Where are you running `@postable.departments.each...`? In a view, controllers, console, etc? It would help if you could post most of the file where you are calling that.

Comment: I did it in post controller as a method and want the result show up in the view.

Comment: Can you please edit your post to include the code as it appears in the controller and view? We need to see the actual code.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I edit it.

Answer (score 0):

Your `put_tag` method isn't returning what you think it's returning. Rather than returning an array of names, the `department.name` several times as an array, all the method does is call that repeatedly and then return `@postable`. You should use `collect` instead of `each` in this scenario:

```
def put_tag
  @postable.departments.collect do |department|
    department.name
  end
end
```

This is equivalent to something like this:

```
def put_tag
  names = []
  @postable.departments.each do |department|
    names << department.name
  end
  names
end
```